# Regular expression ends with specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using `\d{7,11}([A])` to validate my input value. The value must be of length 7 to 11 digits followed by A (capital) always. Above regex returning true for a 
 ( lower case)  also. i.e 1234567a - is true, but this should be false. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Below is my code sample

```
   var patt = new RegExp('^\d{7,11}A$');
   var res1 = patt.test('1234567A'); // O/P : false
   var res2 = patt.test('1234567a'); // O/P : false
```

Comment: Did you try `\d{7,11}A`?

Comment: Could you supply a code snippet showing how you define your Regex object?

Comment: @acattle code snippet is not required here. you've many regex test validation sites are there

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi I'm trying to rule out you passing the "ignore case" option, thus a code snippet would be very useful

Comment: @acattle, i'm not passing ignore case

Comment: Dear downvoters, i'm looking for solution and not for -1 here

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Not sure, how are you using this, it certainly works for me https://ideone.com/4KzkOh

Comment: @sonu Kumar, my regex working fine in C# and not in java script.

Comment: Show us how you use the regex in JS.

Comment: Try this regex `/\d{7,11}A$/`

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi certainly you're doing something wrong, https://jsfiddle.net/sonus21/ooxc81Lb/

Comment: The downvotes are due to the fact that the currently described problem cannot be reproduced. Please provide the code that does **NOT** work. [`1234567a` cannot match `\d{7,11}A$`](https://regex101.com/r/xw5TpP/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/\d{7,11}A$/` to check if your string has digits of length 7 to 11 followed by `A` in the end.

```js
var arr = ['1234567a', '1234567A', '01234567891A', '01234567891B'],
    result = arr.map(s => /\d{7,11}A$/.test(s));
console.log(result);
```